# Kotlin my Location Service is not working in background

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app that takes location information in every 10 seconds. There are no problem when I use it while the app is open. However, when I put it to background, it stops listening new location information. I am using a Service for doing so, but it is not working. How can I take the location information while app is in background?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tts.traffictrackingsystem">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TrafficTrackingSystem">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name= ".MyService"
            android:enabled= "true"
            android:exported= "true">
        </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    package com.tts.traffictrackingsystem

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        val PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,

                )

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //no permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, 1)
        } else{
            //yes permission
            Intent(this, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
                startService(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyService.kt**

```
package com.tts.traffictrackingsystem

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Binder
import android.os.IBinder
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.tts.traffictrackingsystem.data.Data
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.HashMap


class MyService() : Service() {
    lateinit var sharedPreferences : SharedPreferences
    private lateinit var db : FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var locationManager : LocationManager
    private lateinit var locationListener : LocationListener
    var ilkKonum = HashMap<String, Any>()
    var sonKonum = HashMap<String, Any>()
    var kontrolKonum = HashMap<String, Any>()
    lateinit var sonZaman : Timestamp



    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        println("Service started")

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                "com.tts.traffictrackingsystem",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )


        var userId = sharedPreferences.getString("userId", "")

        if (userId == ""){
            println("Kullanıcı yeni, uuid atılıyor.")
            val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userId", uuid.toString()).apply()
            userId = uuid.toString()
            println("UUİD : " + userId)
        } else {
            println("Kullanıcı zaten var, UUİD : " + userId)
        }


        ilkKonum.clear()
        sonKonum.clear()
        kontrolKonum.clear()

        locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        locationListener = object : LocationListener{
            override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                sonKonum.put("latitude", location.latitude)
                sonKonum.put("longitude", location.longitude)
                sonKonum.put("time", Timestamp.now())



                if (ilkKonum == kontrolKonum){
                    println("Yeni başlamış, veriler girildi")
                    //Yeni başlamış
                    ilkKonum.put("latitude", sonKonum.get("latitude")!!)
                    ilkKonum.put("longitude", sonKonum.get("longitude")!!)
                    ilkKonum.put("time", sonKonum.get("time")!!)


                    sonZaman = ilkKonum.get("time") as Timestamp
                    //firebase'e kaydet
                    var la = ilkKonum.get("latitude") as Double
                    var lo = ilkKonum.get("longitude") as Double
                    var data = Data(la, lo, sonZaman, 0.0, userId!!)

                    saveToFirebase(data)
                }
                else {
                    println("Hareket etmiş, değerler hesaplanıyor")
                    //Devam ediyor
                    //Önceki konumla mesafeyi hesapla, hızı hesapla ve firebase'e kaydet
                    var kontrolZaman = sonKonum.get("time") as Timestamp
                    var la1 = ilkKonum.get("latitude") as Double
                    var lo1 = ilkKonum.get("longitude") as Double
                    var la2 = sonKonum.get("latitude") as Double
                    var lo2 = sonKonum.get("longitude") as Double

                    var latlng1 = LatLng(la1, lo1)
                    var latlng2 = LatLng(la2, lo2)




                    if (sonZaman.seconds<50){
                        if (kontrolZaman.seconds -sonZaman.seconds >= -50){
                            //10 saniye sonraki veri
                            val results = FloatArray(1)
                            Location.distanceBetween(la1, lo1, la2, lo2,results)
                            var speed = (results.get(0)/10)*3.6
                            var data = Data(la2, lo2, kontrolZaman, speed, userId!!)
                            saveToFirebase(data)

                            ilkKonum.put("latitude", sonKonum.get("latitude")!!)
                            ilkKonum.put("longitude", sonKonum.get("longitude")!!)
                            ilkKonum.put("time", sonKonum.get("time")!!)


                            sonZaman = kontrolZaman
                            println("Hızlı veri gitti")
                            println("Hız : " + speed)
                            println("${la1} ${la2} ${lo1} ${lo2}")

                        } else {
                            //10 saniye dolmadan gelen veri
                            println("10 Saniye olmadı!")

                        }
                    } else {
                        if (kontrolZaman.seconds -sonZaman.seconds >= 10) {
                            //10 saniye sonraki veri
                            val results = FloatArray(1)
                            Location.distanceBetween(la1, lo1, la2, lo2,results)
                            var speed = (results.get(0)/10)*3.6
                            var data = Data(la2, lo2, kontrolZaman, speed, userId!!)
                            saveToFirebase(data)

                            ilkKonum.put("latitude", sonKonum.get("latitude")!!)
                            ilkKonum.put("longitude", sonKonum.get("longitude")!!)
                            ilkKonum.put("time", sonKonum.get("time")!!)


                            sonZaman = kontrolZaman

                            println("Hızlı veri gitti1")
                            println("Hız : " + speed)
                            println("${la1} ${la2} ${lo1} ${lo2}")

                        } else {
                            //10 saniye dolmadan gelen veri
                            println("10 Saniye olmadı!1")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    1,
                    1f,
                    locationListener
            )

        }



        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }




    override fun onDestroy() {

        println("Service destroyed")
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    fun saveToFirebase(konum: Data){
        val konumHash = HashMap<String, Any>()
        konumHash.put("userId", konum.userId)
        konumHash.put("latitude", konum.latitude)
        konumHash.put("longitude", konum.longitude)
        konumHash.put("time", konum.time)
        konumHash.put("speed", konum.speed)


        db.collection(konum.userId).add(konumHash).addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Veri Gönderildi!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            println("Firebase kaydedildi")
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, it.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must use foreground service. Check this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Comment: @PradeepKumar I used it and it worked, thanks for guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should start your `service` as foreground via `notification`.
But it would be nicer if you listen to your application state and when the application is up you bind your `service` to your activity and when your application moves to the background you bind your `service` to a notification.
but in this answer, I show you how to start a foreground `service` via bind to `notification`.

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, ForegroundControllersService::class.java)
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(applicationContext, serviceIntent)
```

and you should bind your `service` to `notification` like this in `onStartCommand`:

```
val channel = "services"
val notificationCompat = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel)
            .apply {
                if (sdkAndAfter(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)) {
                    setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
                    color = context.color(R.color.blueDeepDark);
                } else {
                    setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
                }
            }
            .apply {
                context.resources.decodeBitmap(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)?.let { setLargeIcon(it) }
            }
val notification = notificationCompat.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)
            .setSound(null)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentText("Your service is going")
            .setContentIntent(
                NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
                    .setGraph(R.navigation.navigation_main)
                    .setDestination(R.id.dashboardFragment)
                    .createPendingIntent()
            )
            .build()
startForeground(123123,notification)
notificationManager?.notify(123123, notification)
```